# Is there a clever way to pass a yml locale file to my client for translation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

I have finished a rails project using i18n and now I need to pass all the text in the website to our client so that he can translate them and we can include additional locales to our app.

The problem is our client is not a geek and if we give them the actual YAML file, they will use MS Word to edit it and we'll lose all the proper markup in the process ("\n" for new lines, one line text, etc...).

How would you handle this process?
Is there a better way than giving the client a .doc file and then loosing a day to clean the text afterwards and manually converting it back to YAML?

Thanks in advance,
Augusto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [Locale](http://www.localeapp.com) was created for : you upload your YAML files, your client/translator edits the content and you sync YAML back down. You don't email files and you don't have to deal with crappy file formats - check it out!

Full disclosure : I co-founded and develop Locale.

Comment: Hi tigrish, I signed up for Localeapp.  Now some new questions.  What if my client wants to add some bold style to texts?  What if he wants to add some bullet points (ul) to a text?  Is there a simple way, avoiding him to enter HTML code inside the text he has to edit?

Comment: Hi Augusto, I find the best way to handle this is by using something like markdown and handling converting it to html at your end. I've found that the syntax is generally simple enough for non technical people to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a one-off thing where I you do the translation once and then be done with it.

What we do in these cases (we usually work with a Translator for these kinds of things) is that we export all the keys in the YAML to Excel and send them that.

Once we get it back we usually task a intern with fixing up the yaml (after it's been translated back into YAML - we do this manually at the moment but a little script should be easy to implement)

Other solutions could be (if you do this a lot) that you include the translations into your app and enable through some JavaScript and maybe something similar to [Aloha Editor](http://aloha-editor.org/) the user to simply click on texts and translate them in the app. But that's a bit excessive and only makes sense if there are really a lot of translations to be done and you want to crowdsource them (Facebook did this back in the day)